# Center Diverging color map on a matrix plot

Tags: plotting, color

I want to use the color function "RedBlueTones" and I want to center the map at a number. Then I want to blend in the red direction of I am greater than that number and blend in the blue direction if I am less than that number.

Here is an example.  How do I center this at 8?

```
MatrixPlot[stackTest, ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones"]
stackTest = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the verbose way. Feel free to make a function of it:

```
stackTest = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
MatrixPlot[stackTest, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["RedBlueTones"][
   1 - If[# < 8, Rescale[#, {1, 8}, {0, 1/2}], Rescale[#, {8, 10}, {1/2, 1}]]]&), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can this be done for an arbitrary list? Where we can specify a target (the center of the color map) and apply it?

Comment: Instead of `ColorData["RedBlueTones"][1 - If[....` you can use `ColorData[{"RedBlueTones", "Reversed"}][If[...`

Comment: @olliepower just read the 8`s in harilutan's ColorFunction as "center" and, in the ranges {1,8}, {8,10}, the 1 as the data minimum and 10 as maximum

Answer (score 2):

Using @halirutan's piecewise re-scaling directly on the input matrix:

```
ClearAll[rsF];

dt = RandomInteger[10, {8, 8}]; 
rsF[lst_, n_] := With[{min = Min @@ lst, max = Max @@ lst}, 
   Map[If[# <= n, Rescale[#, {min, n}, {0, 1/2}],Rescale[#, {n, max}, {1/2, 1}]] &,
       lst, {-1}]]
mp1 = MatrixPlot[rsF[dt, 8], ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"RedBlueTones", "Reversed"}][#] &),
   Epilog -> {Red, MapIndexed[Text[Style[#1, Bold, 20], #2 - {.5, .5}] &,
                    Transpose@Reverse[dt], {2}]}, ImageSize -> 300];
mp2 = MatrixPlot[rsF[dt, 3], ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"RedBlueTones", "Reversed"}][#] &),
   Epilog -> {Red, MapIndexed[Text[Style[#1, Bold, 20], #2 - {.5, .5}] &,
                     Transpose@Reverse[dt], {2}]}, ImageSize -> 300];
mp3 = MatrixPlot[List /@ Range[-1, 1, .2],
   Frame -> False, FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> {50, 280}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["RedBlueTones"][#] &),
   Epilog -> {Red, MapIndexed[ Text[Style[#1, Bold, 20], #2 - {.5, .5}] &, 
                     {Range[0, 10]}, {2}]}];
Row[{Labeled[mp1, "n=8", Top], Labeled[mp2, "n=3", Top], mp3}, Spacer[5]] // Panel
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify exactly how you want to blend which permits an extremely simple interpretation of the question:

```
MatrixPlot[8 - stackTest, ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones"]
```

[image]

Perhaps you could include an example in your question if you are aiming for a *specific* scaling.